# Error msg overlapping editfield when onfocus android

Tags: android, validation, textwatcher

I have generic textwatcher for editext. I have used validation for editext using setError() as shown below

```
private class GenericTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

        private View view;

        private GenericTextWatcher(View view) {
            this.view = view;
        }

        // @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.autocompletetextview:

                isAlphaNumeric = validateEditText("^[a-zA-Z0-9 ,.-]*$", editLocation.getText().toString());

                if (!isAlphaNumeric) {
//                  editLocation.setError(getErrorMsg("Only , . and - are allowed"));
                    editLocation.setError(getText(R.string.invalid_loc_address));
                } else {


                }

            }
        }

        // @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence sequence, int start, int count, int after) {
        }
![enter image description here][1]
        // @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence sequence, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

    }
```

The validation which i am using overlaps the edittext and the value in editext is not visible. Is it possible to shift the error message?
please suggest a suitable solution for the issue

Comment: are you using same edittext.??

Comment: yes, i am using the same edittext

Comment: then you should use textview for display error..

Comment: could you please brief your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Take Textview component int your xml file. give id `tvError`.

```
TextView tvError = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvError);

private class GenericTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

        private View view;

        private GenericTextWatcher(View view) {
            this.view = view;
        }

        // @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.autocompletetextview:

                isAlphaNumeric = validateEditText("^[a-zA-Z0-9 ,.-]*$", editLocation.getText().toString());

                if (!isAlphaNumeric) {

                    tvError.setText(getText(R.string.invalid_loc_address));
                } else {


                }

            }
        }

        // @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence sequence, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        // @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence sequence, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

    }
```